# PHP to save file with JSON format

Tags: php, json

I want to save a file as JSON, with the JSON format using PHP.

Currently I have this code, but instead of `variables.txt`, I want to save as `variables.json`, with the JSON file format, something like this:

`{
   ssh_user: teste,
   ssh_pw: teste
}`

This is my PHP code:

```php
<?php
    extract($_REQUEST);
    $file=fopen("variables.txt","w");

    fwrite($file,"ssh_user: ");
    fwrite($file, $username ."\n");
    fwrite($file,"ssh_pw: ");
    fwrite($file, $password ."\n");
    fclose($file);
?>
```

This may sound confusing, but can someone give me a tip? Thank you.

Comment: Are you familiar with the json_encode() function?

Comment: @ADyson not really, I'm kinda new on JSON and PHP stuff...

Comment: @ADyson is what you need. Create and object with those fields and use json_encode to create the json string you need to write to the file. I'd question why you are storing usernames and passwords in plaintext files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file_put_contents('variables.json', json_encode([
    'ssh_user' => $_REQUEST['username'] ?? null,
    'ssh_pw'   => $_REQUEST['password'] ?? null,
]));
```

Please note that your code `extract($_REQUEST)` can have security implications.